# Bot fails to start when subcommand have two options [Discord.py, Discord-py-slash-command]

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

If I try to add two options to a subcommand, the bot won't work. But if I add one argument (autocomplete). The bot is working. How can I fix this?

This code dont work:

```
@bot.command(
    name="test_command",
    description="Just a test command",
    scope=GUILD_ID,
    options = [
        interactions.Option(
            name="sub1",
            description="The first subcommand",
            type=interactions.OptionType.SUB_COMMAND,
            options=[
                interactions.Option(
                    name="opt1",
                    description="The first option",
                    type=interactions.OptionType.STRING,
                    required=True,
                ),
                interactions.Option(
                    name="opt2",
                    description="The second option",
                    type=interactions.OptionType.STRING,
                    required=True
                )
            ]
        )
    ]
)
async def test_cmd(ctx: interactions.CommandContext, sub_command, opt1, opt2):
    await ctx.send(f"You Chose: {opt1}, {opt2}!")
```

But his code work:

```
@bot.command(
    name="test_command",
    description="Just a test command",
    scope=GUILD_ID,
    options = [
        interactions.Option(
            name="sub1",
            description="The first subcommand",
            type=interactions.OptionType.SUB_COMMAND,
            options=[
                interactions.Option(
                    name="opt1",
                    description="The first option",
                    type=interactions.OptionType.STRING,
                    required=True,
                    autocomplete=True                      #I ADDED THIS LINE
                ),
                interactions.Option(
                    name="opt2",
                    description="The second option",
                    type=interactions.OptionType.STRING,
                    required=True
                )
            ]
        )
    ]
)
async def test_cmd(ctx: interactions.CommandContext, sub_command, opt1, opt2):
    await ctx.send(f"You Chose: {opt1}, {opt2}!")
```

On the official site there is an example with a subcommand with 2 options, so I think it should work

Solved: The problem was in the library that I was using. I installed the version from GitHub and it worked, pip version not working

Comment: Why does it fail to start? Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.